# How to stretch Rectangle over Grid cell in XAML

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I need to add a rectangle in second row of the grid.
I need rectangle to have width same as the width of Grid.

But the problem is, width of grid is decided at runtime. If I try to access `Width` or `ActualWidth` at the back code, I get `NaN` or `0.0` respectively.

`ColumnSpan` and `Stretch` are not working either.
Here is the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="downloadPdfGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Content="{Binding Button}" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="OnButtonClick" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="underlineRect" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="2" Fill="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="underlineRect" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="2" Fill="White"
           Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
           Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>
```

Or if you have the Grid's name:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="underlineRect" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="2" Fill="White"
           Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
           Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=downloadPdfGrid}"/>
```

Edit: I forgot. I haven't worked much with Rectangle per se, but this might work too:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="underlineRect" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="2" Fill="White"
           Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Comment: Then there is something else apart from the grid that you are not showing. I've just fired up a blank WPF application with only your grid inside the window and tested your original code and all three alterations proposed and they all worked (including your own).

Comment: You are right. The problem was due to the parent element.
Thank you Simon. It works perfectly fine now.